# Install 20.04 along side Win 10 home edition

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04

Ubuntu install stops at the point it says Bitlocker will cause problems if not turned off in Windows. Bitlocker is not available in the Home edition so there is no way to turn it off. Ubuntu install only gives the option to restart at the Bitlocker notification screen. How does one get past this halt in the installation?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to disable Secure Boot in your BIOS settings to bypass that error. Secure Boot usually interferes with a normal Ubuntu installation anyway due to unsigned drivers and possibly Microsoft CSCA's only being trusted (shim-signed does fix this issue, though), and other unusual behavior. BitLocker also relies on Secure Boot.

Another plausible, but unlikely, cause could be that Windows could've possibly formatted your Windows partition or hard drive as BitLocker, even if you aren't using it, resulting in the hard drive partitioning and structure becoming unreliable, as BitLocker partitions aren't designed to be resized, and in some situations, can encrypt the entire drive to the point of being unable to safely operate on it. [See this article for more information.](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-running-windows-and-bitlocker-turned-on/15338)

HTH!

Comment: I disabled Secure Boot and had to turn off Device Encryption to install Ubuntu 20.04 along side Win 10. Thanks Garret Stand!

Comment: Next problem is wondering why 'Install along side Windows' is not offered as an option in the Install process now. The only options listed are Erase and Something Else. This means partitioning the Windows disk manually.

Comment: Deselecting Third Party Software lets the Install Along Side Windows option show up, where selecting it causes the option to NOT be listed.

Comment: I wouldn't know why exactly third party software would hinder dual boot installation, especially with Secure Boot off, but shrinking the C: drive in Windows using `diskmgmt.msc` and partitioning the free space in the installer for Ubuntu and selecting the appropriate ESP should allow you to install it in a dual boot fashion.